# How do you set up a for loop which basically goes around in a cyclic pattern for a set amount of numbers? For example, how to go from 123 to 231to 312

Tags: python, for-loop, design-patterns, cyclic

could someone please show me how to approach this type of question as I am revising for my end of semester exams.

> Write a function cyclical(n) that produces an n ×n pattern in which the
> numbers 0 to n −1 appear in every row, but where the numbers in each row
> are cyclically shifted with respect to those in the row above. (7 marks)
>
> ```
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0
> 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 1
> 3 4 5 6 7 0 1 2
> 4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3
> 5 6 7 0 1 2 3 4
> 6 7 0 1 2 3 4 5
> 7 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
> ```

This is what I have so far:

```py
answer=0
for i in range(0,8):
    for i in range(0,8):
        answer=i+1
        print(answer,end="")
    print()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You are using 2 "for" loops with a single variable.

Check out the docs to understand the basic of for loops:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Also use 'start' and 'end' parameters and modulo to your advantage:

```py
def cyclical(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i, i + n):
            print(j % n, end = '')
        print('')

cyclical(7)
```